# OSX Browser does not display certain special Unicode characters/symbols

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, missing-symbols

OSX 10.14.6,
Safari 13.0.4 (Unicode UTF-8),
Firefox 72.0.1,

From this screen shot you can see about 2/3 of the way down the page my browser stops displaying certain special characters leaving just a square box. 
[image: some characters dont display]

https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/35-symbols/arrows

I have pasted this link into all the browsers I have and the results are the same.

This leads me to conclude that I am missing some system font of some kind or the one I have is corrupted or incomplete or something.

If you know how to fix this please advise.